# PHP - return NULL if no value of FETCH_ASSOC?

Tags: php, class

my function returns an array from a MySQL query, is it good to return NULL if MySQL returns no results? Thank you

```
class User
{
    /* ... */

    /**
    * Return user info for specified user id
    * @param int $user_id
    * @return array $user
    */
    public function getUser(int $user_id): ?array {

        $query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id LIMIT 1');
        $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));

        $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ( is_array($user) && !empty($user) ) {

            return $user;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**UPDATE:** after reading the link above, finally I will do like this.

```
class User
{
    /* ... */

    /**
    * Return user info for specified user id
    * @param int $user_id
    * @return array $user
    */
    public function getUser(int $user_id): array {

        $user = array();

        $query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id LIMIT 1');
        $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));

        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ( is_array($result) && !empty($result) ) {

          foreach( $result as $key => $value ) {

             $user[$key] =  $value;
          }
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a (single) good way of doing this (although there are bad ways of doing it).  Some prefer to return false, in the case of a method in a class it would be more common to set the fields within the class rather than return the data to the caller.

Comment: As @NigelRen said, its more common to set the result into a class Property and access them from outside.
You could have a property `public $user;` and when you initialize an object of the class you could easily call the method and then access the property `$user`

Comment: You're going to return at most one user at a time; returning *an array of one user* seems extremely odd.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i think that’s fine. I would probably do something similar. Then when coding with that you can do something like

```
if (getUser())
{
 //code assumes user exists 
}
```

Comment: Also I’m pretty sure the fetch returns false if ones not returned. Test that but you might be able to simplify the bottom half to if $user return true else return null